# Can I move the items that I have already copied in Array?

Tags: modifiers

I would like to do some barrels and in the top more. I use Array.

My problem is that I can't move the last barrel on the top. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might apply the array, so it becomes one large object, then separate object in edit mode press P loose parts, now you can re-position all separated objects.

Comment: I have tried some times but they are not separated plus I have more objects disorganise

Comment: make sure you are in mesh edit mode, pressing P will only work in mesh edit mode, it wont work in object mode. (its at the bottom of that panel a pull-down menu)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but it doesn't work. Maybe because I have an object with so many details. I put it everything together before. To be honest I don't know why it doesn't work. I have found another answer. Your help is appreciated.